# Absolute extrema of a multivariable function bounded by an ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, absolute-value

I have a function $f(x,y) = 2x + x^2 + y^2$ bounded by the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 \leq 24$

I know how to determine the extrema within the ellipse by getting the partial derivatives and setting them to zero, but I don't really understand how to determine the extrema at the boundaries of the ellipse.

I know that the parametric equation for the ellipse is $(x, y) = (a\cos(t), b\sin(t))$ where $a = \sqrt{24}$ and $b = \sqrt 6$ but I don't really know how to use this formula for determining the extrema at those coordinates.

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: Yes, but the question is for the chapter preceding the chapter on Lagrange Multipliers. The question implies that I'm supposed to do it parametrically.

Comment: Well, at the boundary you can transform this in a typical one variable calculus problem by setting $y=\pm \dfrac {\sqrt{24-x^2}}2$. Not sure how complicated this will become though..

Comment: You don't have have to take the square root because you just have $y^2$ on $f$, so just replace $y^2$ with $\dfrac {20-x^2}{4}$. You got yourself a polynomial. Enjoy.

Comment: Gitgud means $\frac{ 24-x^2} { 4} $. (Sorry for deleting my previous comment. I thought you would made the edit, but then realized that you can't.)

Comment: Would that give me the extrema at the border? Should I take that new function with the substitution and find its critical points? Will that give me that maximums/minimums at the boundary or do I need to take more steps?

Comment: @Cranky That will give you the extrema at the boundary, yes. It's a classical calculus problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The minima , in the interior of the elliptical region occurs at (-1,0) where z takes the value -1. On the boundary of the ellipse, the maxima occurs at $(2\sqrt(6,0)$ where z takes the value $4(6 + \sqrt(6)$. Notice there are three more
critical points here, one is a local maxima, two are local minima .

I've updated this drawing since I discovered that I wrote down the parameters of the elliptical cylinder wrong, sorry !

Again, just for fun, assume the y coordinate is zero, then $x^2 = 24$ , so x is $2\sqrt{6}$ , yes the negative root should also be checked. And, $2x + x^2$ takes the value  $24 + 4\sqrt{6}$ a local maxima.

Comment: (-1, 0) = -1 is what I got as well. I don't know how to arrive at the maxima though.

Comment: Sorry , I wrote down the parameters in the ellipse wrong!

Comment: That's the value that I got with the help from the other guys as well. Thanks.